# How can I have a "Dear %firstname%" template in my Gmail?

Tags: gmail

It seems to be a very easy thing but I am struggling to see how. I need a "Dear %firstname%,  [cursor here] Kind Regards etc" template in my Gmail account, so every time I click reply, it is already there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

With the Gmail web client, you can't. You can create a [signature](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8395), and you can create [canned responses](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/10/new-in-labs-canned-responses.html), but neither of those things can contain dynamic variable tags.

Comment: I use the format `Dear __FIRST_NAME__` in my canned responses, so it's easy to spot and change manually, just double click and it's all selected and ready to change.